# How to use a variable in SELECT AS in MySQL, to specify the displayed column name?

Tags: mysql

I have here assigned "test123" to the variable **@searchstring**.
I would like the name of the display column to be the value of the variable (ie. **test123** in this case).

This is what I issued in MySQL console:

```
SET @searchstring="test123";  #SET the searchstring you want to search
SELECT DISTINCT(caselist.casenumber1) AS "@searchstring"    FROM caselist LIMIT 1;
```

This is what I got returned on screen:

```
+---------------+
| @searchstring |
+---------------+
|             0 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The desired result is this:

```
+---------------+
| test123       |
+---------------+
|             0 |
+---------------+
```

My actual query issued will be more complex, and refers to  the @searchstring multiple times.
The content of @searchstring changes, depending on what I want to search.
That is why I decided to assign a value to it upfront once. When I want to search other things, I just need to change that variable once upfront.

**QUESTION:
How do I have the column title to display the **content of the variable** @searchstring (ie. test123 in this case), rather than the actual name of the variable?**

Thank you.

If I do this (ie. remove the quotation marks around the variable name after AS):

```
SET @searchstring="test123";  #SET the searchstring you want to search
SELECT DISTINCT(caselist.casenumber1) AS @searchstring  FROM caselist ;
```

Then I get this error message:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(caselist.casenumber1) AS @searchstring FROM caselist ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@searchstring FROM caselist' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: You cannot by this way. Object name is literal, not expression.

Comment: There must be a problem behind the question which we don't know and most likely can be solved more elegantly. In most cases I've seen, variable identifiers have been a bad (if not a terrible) idea.

Answer (score 3):

One option is using dynamic querying for this problem:

```
SET @searchstring = "test123";  #SET the searchstring you want to search

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT casenumber1 AS ',
                  @searchstring,
                  ' FROM caselist LIMIT 1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddwwLy73uSuwiPE4VJ78ac/1).

Comment: This is the only possibility to solve within MySQL.

Comment: It's the same in any other implementation of SQL. Identifiers != values.

Comment: Note: This opens a door for SQL injections, as long as the source of the assigned variable is unclear.